# Using .bib files in central directory in MikTex 2.9 on Windows 7

Tags: bibliographies, miktex

I am very new at LaTeX, so please bear with me if I am re-posting something. I have found a lot of info online, but nothing simple enough for me to duplicate it.

I am trying to set-up my document to use a bib file in a local directory, so that multiple documents can share the same bib file. I will need the tex files to be able to link to this bib file, regardless of the tex file location on my machine.

I have the following code to start my document,

```
\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\title{Connecting  a detection system net for Interplanetary counterparts of Coronal Mass Events to warning signals aimed in a spherical pattern to activate automated emergencies procedures aboard interplanetary space craft}
\author{\firstname{Sara-jeanne} Vogler}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\section{Premises}
    hello\cite{Vog13a}
\section{Technique}
    \subsection{Timeline}
\section{Evaluation}
\bibliography{C:/LocalTexFiles/bibtex/bib/sarabibs}
\end{document}
```

My bib file is in C:\LocalTexFiles\bibtex\bib\misc and C:\LocalTexFiles has been added as a Root Directory in MikTex Maintenance Options.

The messages during compile says

> I couldn't open database file C:/LocalTexFiles/bibtex/bib/sarabibs.bib
>   and the pdf shows a ? instead of a numerical citation within the text.

Comment: Use simply \bibliography{sarabibs}

Comment: Well, you no need to complicate your life so much. I'm not shure why you should not place your `.bib` file in that path. Just to be tidy and have everything in the same directory. Just place the `.bib` file in that folder and ensures that your `.tex` documents will use that `.bib` file are on the same directory or in a subdirectory and problem solved. You don't need to specify paths.

Answer (score 1):

For example, I have stored central master bib file in the path:

*c:\Users\jafa\Documents\Wiking\localtexmf\bibtex\bib\local\MasterBiblioLib.bib*

Subdirectories **\localtexmf\bibtex\bib\local** are required. Then, in the MikTeX
options on card Roots add your path. It works also on Windows 10.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also met this perplexing problem. I want multiple `.tex` files  can share the same `.bib` file. Actually, using absolute directory paths  is hard to accomplish this task. I usually try to add  the absolute path of  my`.bib` file in the MiKTeX options, but never succeed.  Below is my method to handle this problem with the way of relative path.

If your `.bib` file is in the directory `C:\LocalTexFiles\bibtex\bib\sarabibs.bib`,  put your `.tex` file into a  folder named `mytexfile` (the folder's name is arbitrary), and put this folder into `C:\LocalTexFiles\`. At the end of your `.tex` file, use `\bibliography{../bibtex/bib/sarabibs}` instead of `\bibliography{C:/LocalTexFiles/bibtex/bib/sarabibs}`. 
This describes the relative path between your `.bib` file and your `.tex` file. The common path `C:\LocalTexFiles` is represented by `..`, and the relative part is `/bibtex/bib/sarabibs`.

Your `.tex` file can reside in the folder `mytexfile`, which is separate from other irrelevant files, and that reaches the objective. And you will find that your `.tex` file runs well again. This is a method of relative paths, with the advantage that this method doesn't require you to add the path of  your`.bib` file in the MiKTeX options.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That's much more complicated and as the OP has a kind of special setup it's maybe not the best solution.